# java returns day of week instead of month

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

NB: yes I realize that using simple date format may well be better than my current system, but I find this easier than using simple date format.

This code should simply return the date saved as dd/mm/yyyy, and it does so for the loan date 1/1/2013, however for the dueBack date it returns 22/4/2013, it should be returning 22/1/2013.

```
public String returnLoan()
{
    String dLoan = loan.get(loan.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" 
                     + loan.get(loan.MONTH + 1) + "/" 
                     + loan.get(loan.YEAR);
    return dLoan;
}

public String returnDueBack()
{
    String dDueBack = dueBack.get(dueBack.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" 
                        + dueBack.get(dueBack.MONTH + 1) + "/" 
                        + dueBack.get(dueBack.YEAR);
    return dDueBack;
}
```

for reference this is the constructor

```
public Loan()
{
    memID = 0;
    bookID = 0;
    loan = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 1);
    dueBack = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 22);
    returned = false;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "NB: yes I realize that using simple date format may well be better than my current system, but I find this easier than using simple date format." Kind of seems like a good time to learn, rather than hacking around the problem.

Comment: In particular, your code isn't doing 0-padding - whereas if you just create a `SimpleDateFormat` with a pattern of `dd/MM/yyyy` it will work *really* simply. And you wouldn't have the current problem. How can you say that the "current system" is easier than using `SimpleDateFormat` when the current system doesn't work yet?

Answer (score 9):

Instead of

```
dueBack.get(dueBack.MONTH + 1)
```

use

```
dueBack.get(dueBack.MONTH) + 1
```

Comment: They need a new Calendar system which uses enums for these things, instead of constants. Less prone to errors like these

Comment: @Cruncher It's going to get better in Java 8 with the new [`java.time`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: @Jesper It looks good. It seems strange that it's taken this long for a decent time package. Of course Jon Skeet is going to yell at me, telling me that it's really not that easy.

Comment: @Cruncher The new `java.time` package is based on the popular [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. If you can't use Java 8, then I highly recommend using Joda Time if you need to do anything with dates and times. Its API is much better than what `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` offer.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse(                                // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    "22/4/2013" , 
     DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d/M/uuuu" )  // Formatting pattern to match input.
)                                               // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.plusMonths( 1 )                                // Move to the next month. Returns another `LocalDate` object.
.toString()                                     // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2013-05-22

## java.time

Much easier to use the modern *java.time* classes.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

```
String input = "22/4/2013" ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d/M/uuuu" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDate`, a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Add a month.

```
LocalDate ldNextMonth = ld.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).